# Trigger external pipeline / job after Jira in OpenShift startet

Tags: openshift, jira, webhooks

I'm running jira in openshift using the basic image from atlassian: https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software

So far most things work fine.

I installed a plugin using the web ui which worked as well.

But now I'm running into an issue when a pod is restarted. The pod uses the image and naturally (as specified) my plugin is not installed anymore. I can install the plugin via webservice calls and register it as an osgi module for jira. But I don't want to do this manually. Building a pipeline or jon for this is quite easy (I'm thinking jenkins or ansible tower). But I so far I didn't find a way to trigger this pipeline after the pod is started (or better after jira is started).

Anyone got an idea how to handle this?

Thanks and best regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom image based on the Atlassian image with everything you need installed?

As far as I know, there isn't a way to trigger a pipeline when a Pod is started; only Webhook, Image Change, and Config Change [triggers](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html#image-change-triggers) are available. You'll need to write a Jenkinsfile to script all of the installation and setup you want, but then that can be triggered in one of the three ways mentioned.

I'm thinking an Image Change trigger would work best for you, so when the latest version of Atlassian's image comes out, you can run your pipeline to set everything up on the latest version.

Also, just curious, but do you have some persistent storage attached to the Jira pod? If not, you'll lose everything in Jira if the Pod dies; that means tickets, boards, comments, everything.

### Update:

Looking at [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/important-directories-and-files-861253886.html), it looks like most of the stuff you're trying to persist is stored in [jira-home](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/jira-application-home-directory-861253888.html), so maybe mounting that as a persistent volume will be a good solution for you.

You're correct that the tickets are stored in the database, but I'm guessing the database connection settings are getting wiped when the Pod is cycled.

The jira-home directory stores your application and database connection settings, as well as a subdirectory for your plugins.

> **dbconfig.xml**
>
> This file (located at the root of your JIRA home directory) defines
> all details for JIRA's database connection. This file is typically
> created by running the JIRA setup wizard on new installations of JIRA
> or by configuring a database connection using the JIRA configuration
> tool.
>
> You can also create your own dbconfig.xml file. This is useful if you
> need to specify additional parameters for your specific database
> configuration, which are not generated by the setup wizard or JIRA
> configuration tool. For more information, refer to the 'manual'
> connection instructions of the appropriate database configuration
> guide in Connecting JIRA to a database.
>
> **jira-config.properties**
>
> This file (also located at the root of your JIRA home directory)
> stores custom values for most of JIRA's advanced configuration
> settings. Properties defined in this file override the default values
> defined in the jpm.xml file (located in your JIRA application
> installation directory). See Advanced JIRA configuration for more
> information.
>
> In new JIRA installations, this file may not initially exist and if
> so, will need to be created manually. See Making changes to the
> jira-config.properties file for more information. This file is
> typically present in JIRA installations upgraded from version 4.3 or
> earlier, whose advanced configuration options had been customized
> (from their default values).
>
> **plugins/**
>
> This is the directory where plugins built on Atlassian's Plugin
> Framework 2 (i.e. 'Plugins 2' plugins) are stored. If you are
> installing a new 'Plugins 2' plugin, you will need to deploy it into
> this directory under the installed-plugins sub-directory.
>
> 'Plugins 1' plugins should be stored in the JIRA application
> installation directory.
>
> This directory is created on JIRA startup, if it does not exist
> already.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not closer to the solution but I'll try your suggestions. For your question: as of now there is no persistent storage. But I already figured out that this would help. I'll try to make the plugins directory persistent in hopes that the plugin installations will still work after restart. I notices that tickets are lost after pod restart. But I thought they are stored in the database (external postgres). So I wondered why the tickets are gone. Do you know which directory must be persistent?